# EclipseLink, DescriptorEvent inconsistency, is it really post-commit?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink [DescriptorEventListener interface](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorEventListener.html).

In the `postUpdate` method I receive notification that an entity has updated. If I extract the entity object from the event (by using [getObject()](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorEvent.html#getObject()) on the event) then I have an object which contains the *new* values of the object. This is as expected. The documentation isn't precise on this but I'm assuming that 'postUpdate' also implies post-commit ??

From the event I now notify another thread that this entity has updated. This other thread performs a re-query on the database using the PK of object. Now, the strange thing is that the object returned from the re-query has the *old* values of the object (i.e. pre-update). Why ?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.6 and using the JPA 2.1 interface. The database is Oracle 12. Personally I believe the issues has to do with the fact that EclipseLink has a session-wide entity cache and I bet that re-requery never actually hits the database. Or maybe it does. Don't know.

Any clues as to what is going on ?  Is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: Post Update is after the update statement, not after the transaction commits.  If you want transactional listeners, you want a session listener interface https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/SessionEventListener.html

Comment: Yeah, well. In that case I find the [Javadoc for postUpdate()](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/descriptors/DescriptorEventListener.html) extremely misleading: "This event is raised after an object updated *in the database*."

Comment: Its splitting hairs, but that is accurate.  The statement executes and the event is fired.  It is updated in the database, and reads through your transaction will see the change, but your transaction continues.